# How can search a HTML DOM using firefox debugger?

Tags: html, firefox, dom, javascript-debugger

In the browser debugger, tab "Inspector" there's a field "search", but when I enter the id of tag the seach does not offer any result, in spite of the fact that the tag with this id *is* there. Can it be that this search field can only find tag names, like "span" or "div"? If so, is there a way for me to seach tag IDs using firefox debugger?

Usually I use Chrome debugger where the search in the debugger works like I expect it. But now I need to debug an issue that is specific to firefox. So I am unfamiliar with the firefox debugger. My google-search for `firefox debugger search html` did not return any helpful results.

I'm using Firefox version 36.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search box uses CSS selectors. So if you want to enumerate all file inputs you put `input[type=file]` into the box and keep hitting return until you find the right element if there are multiple matches.

I don't know about FF36, but on 39 (current nightly) it has auto-completion for ID selectors and also validates the input for correct selector syntax.